# Display Timer while a command is being executed in a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

Edit:
I shall thank Magoo for the detailed answer.
I edited my batch file according to Magoo's answer.
Here is the new code:

```
@echo off
mode 62,22
:Begin
choice /c 12345 /M "Insert a number (min. 1 - max. 5): "
set "CommandVar0=%errorlevel%"
choice /c 12345 /M "Please confirm the number you entered: "
set "CommandVarC=%errorlevel%"

if %CommandVarC% NEQ %CommandVar0% (
 echo Insert a matching number between 1~5 for confirmation
 goto Begin
)

if %CommandVar0% == 1 set /P CommandVar1=Insert ID: 
if %CommandVar0% == 2 set /P CommandVar1=Insert ID: & set /P CommandVar2=Insert ID: 
if %CommandVar0% == 3 set /P CommandVar1=Insert ID: & set /P CommandVar2=Insert ID: & set /P CommandVar3=Insert ID: 
if %CommandVar0% == 4 set /P CommandVar1=Insert ID: & set /P CommandVar2=Insert ID: & set /P CommandVar3=Insert ID: & set /P CommandVar4=Insert ID: 
if %CommandVar0% == 5 set /P CommandVar1=Insert ID: & set /P CommandVar2=Insert ID: & set /P CommandVar3=Insert ID: & set /P CommandVar4=Insert ID: & set /P CommandVar5=Insert ID: 

:loop
start EXAMPLE.exe %CommandVar1%
if defined commandvar2 start EXAMPLE.exe %CommandVar2%
if defined commandvar3 start EXAMPLE.exe %CommandVar3%
if defined commandvar4 start EXAMPLE.exe %CommandVar4%
if defined commandvar5 start EXAMPLE.exe %CommandVar5%
rem wait 10 seconds
for /L %%y in (1,1,10) do (
 timeout /t 1 > nul
 tasklist /fi "imagename eq EXAMPLE.exe" |find ":" > nul
 if NOT errorlevel 1 goto begin
)
taskkill /f /im EXAMPLE.exe
timeout /t 5 
goto loop
```

The issue I'm having right now is that;

1. Due to my lack of knowledge, I don't know how to expand this command:

```
set "commandvar1="
set "commandvar2="
set /P CommandVar1=Insert ID: 
if not defined commandvar1 goto begin
if "%CommandVar0%"=="2" (
 set /P CommandVar2=Insert ID: 
 if not defined commandvar2 goto begin
)
```

e.g. to set "commandvar5=" etc. So instead I'm still using my complicated command which does the job for now.

2. How can I add the normal timer to this command?

```
for /L %%y in (1,1,10) do (
 timeout /t 1 > nul
 tasklist /fi "imagename eq EXAMPLE.exe" |find ":" > nul
 if NOT errorlevel 1 goto begin
)
```

I want a timer to actually display the countdown of the command being executed like the usual timeout /t command if possible.

Comment: I am not going to read that wall of text. Can you maybe add line breaks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Addressing the core of the problem:

```
start EXAMPLE.exe %CommandVar1% & start EXAMPLE.exe %CommandVar2%
```

Will `start` two instances of `example.exe` passing the contents of `commandvar?` which may be `response to "Insert ID:"` or (rarely) *nothing*

**Immediately** thereafter, you are executing `tasklist` and looking for `:`.

If **either** the tasks have actually been established and is running, the `tasklist` output will **NOT** contain `:` so `find` will **NOT** find `:` and hence set `errorlevel` to `1`

If the tasks have **not** been started or have both terminated, then the output of `tasklist` would be `INFO: No tasks are running which match the specified criteria.` which contains `:` and hence `errorlevel` will be set to `0`.

Your next line says `if **either** task is running (errorlevel 1), say "not found" and go to Begin` ***otherwise*** (ie. **neither** task is running) then delay, taskkill the non-existent tasks, delay again and go back to `Begin`.

Another hidden problem is that when the routine returns to `begin`, if `CommandVar2` has been `set`, then it will not be cleared, so it will remain set for the next input-cycle, regardless of the data input.

So we need to tackle the logic problems as well as the batch-syntax-specific problems.

Tip: Use `set "var=value"` for setting string values - this avoids problems caused by trailing spaces. Don't assign `"` or a terminal backslash or Space. Build pathnames from the elements - counterintuitively, it is likely to make the process easier. If the syntax `set var="value"` is used, then the quotes become part of the value assigned.

First thing to tackle is the choose-and-check part. The value assigned to a variable by a `set /p` can be any string. That string may be the expected string or an unexpected string (obviously). An unexpected string may take many forms - it might contain spaces for instance, or unbalanced quotes, or `%` or parentheses or other strings or characters that have significance in the batch language. Also, responding with <kbd>Enter</kbd> to a `set /p` will leave the variable **unchanged**, not set it to *nothing*.

When the obvious parameter-check is executed via `if %var1% == %var2% ...`, then the values of the variables are substituted, and the comparison executed, so had the user input `break me` for instance, then batch would attempt to execute `if break me == 2 ...` and batch would see `me` where it expects to see a comparison-operator like `==`.

The usual way to by-pass this problem is by "quoting both sides", ie. `if "%var1%" == "%var2%" ...` This is useful in the case that you may be processing some string containing spaces that is being returned from a command, but what happens if the user enters `break " me` ?

Consequently, the recommendation is to use the `choice` command to make 1-character choices (see `choice /?` from the prompt for documentation, or thousands of items on SO for examples)

Hence, your code should be

```
choice /c 12 /M "Insert a number (min. 1 - max. 2): "
set "CommandVar0=%errorlevel%"
choice /c 12 /M "Please confirm the number you entered: "
set "CommandVarC=%errorlevel%"
```

At this point, we are sure that `commandvar?` contains `1` or `2`, so we can indeed use

```
if %CommandVarC% NEQ %CommandVar0% (
 echo Insert a matching number between 1~2 for confirmation
 goto Begin
)
```

Note: I've used the string-assignment syntax, even though the value assigned from `%errorlevel%` must be a pure-numeric string. It's also possible to use `set /a var=%errorlevel%` here. `set /a` assigns a value that we know is numeric (and can also do calculations) and needs no quotes.

There's no point in `else...` here -it serves to complicate matters. The code will simply continue to the next line if the `goto` is not executed.

```
 if %CommandVarC% GTR 2 (echo Maximum number is 2.
    goto Begin
    ) else (
```

is not required. We know that `CommandVarC` can only be `1` or `2`.

```
if %CommandVar0% == 1 set /P CommandVar1=Insert ID: 
if %CommandVar0% == 2 set /P CommandVar1=Insert ID: & set /P CommandVar2=Insert ID:
```

Well, this is overcomplicated, and doesn't quite do what is required. `CommandVar1` is **always** required, and `CommandVar2` will remain `set` if it has been `set` in the past.

Try:

```
set "commandvar1="
set "commandvar2="
set /P CommandVar1=Insert ID: 
if not defined commandvar1 goto begin
if %CommandVar0% == 2 set /P CommandVar2=Insert ID:
```

Well, primitively. We know `commandvar0` is a single digit, so we can use a simple `==`. We also may or may not have received a response for `commandvar2`.

So

```
if "%CommandVar0%"=="2" (
 set /P CommandVar2=Insert ID: 
 if not defined commandvar2 goto begin
)
```

may be more "according to Hoyle"

Summing up (before we tackle the next part), try using

```
choice /c 12 /M "Insert a number (min. 1 - max. 2): "
set "CommandVar0=%errorlevel%"
choice /c 12 /M "Please confirm the number you entered: "
set "CommandVarC=%errorlevel%"

if %CommandVarC% NEQ %CommandVar0% (
 echo Insert a matching number between 1~2 for confirmation
 goto Begin
) 

set "commandvar1="
set "commandvar2="
set /P CommandVar1=Insert ID: 
if not defined commandvar1 goto begin
if "%CommandVar0%"=="2" (
 set /P CommandVar2=Insert ID: 
 if not defined commandvar2 goto begin
)
```

If we get past this point, I gather we should launch the executable, possibly twice, then wait for it to run, with a run-time limit of 10 seconds.

So,

```
start EXAMPLE.exe %CommandVar1%
rem only start a second instance if commandvar2 has been specified
if defined commandvar2 start EXAMPLE.exe %CommandVar2%
rem wait a sec...or 10
for /L %%y in (1,1,10) do (
 timeout /t 1 >nul
 tasklist /fi "imagename eq EXAMPLE.exe" |find ":" > nul
 if NOT errorlevel 1 goto begin
)
rem kill tasks still running
taskkill /f /im EXAMPLE.exe
timeout /t 5 
goto begin
```

`for /L` is explained at `for /?` from the prompt. Here, it counts `%%y` from 1 to 10 in steps of 1.

Each step delays 1 second (the >nul suppresses the countdown) then tests whether an executable is running. If **NONE** is running, then the `tasklist` will report a line containing `:` and `errorlevel` will be set to `0`.

`IF ERRORLEVEL n` is TRUE if the runtime (ie. current) `errorlevel` is n **or greater than n**. `IF ERRORLEVEL 0` is therefore always true. `IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1` is a test for errorlevel=0.

So, if there is no executable running, goto `begin`.

Once this test has been done 10 times, if an executable is running, then we exit the `for /L` loop and `taskkill` the remaining task(s) and back to the future...

--- To add Commandvars ---

The method is limited to 9 items without complications.

Change the `12` in the `choice` commands to `123456789` (or whatever your limit is).

add

```
for /L %%e in (1,1,9) do set "commandvar%%e="
```

in place of `set "commandvar1="  set "commandvar2="`

This will set all variablenames `commandvar1..9` to *nothing*.

Then

```
for /L %%e in (1,1,9) do (
 set /P CommandVar%%e="Insert ID for instance %%e: "
 if not defined commandvar%%e (
  if %%e==1 goto begin
  goto startprocs
 )
)
:startprocs
for /L %%e in (1,1,9) do if defined commandvar%%e call start "Instance %%e" u:\dummy.bat %%commandvar%%e%%
```

Note that the `set/p` has a quoted prompt-string. This allows the string to have a terminal space. It's possible to have that string "nude" but if your editor gets over-enthusiastic and removes terminal spaces, then you'd lose that one. It also serves to make the space obvious (stray spaces can cause havoc in batch)

Then input your data.
If the first entry is empty, back to the start. You could change that `goto` to an `exit`, which would terminate the `cmd` instance. or `exit /b` which would terminate this batch, but keep your `cmd` session open.

If any other entry is empty, it's the signal to start processing as we've finished our list.

The `for /L` for starting the processes has been changed a little. First, the `start` is immediately followed by a quoted string. This is the title which would appear in the process's window. It could be empty if you wish, but it should not be omitted in the general case. `Start` regards the first quoted string in the command as the window title to be used, so if it is omitted, a quoted string in the command may be eaten by `start`, used as a title and not passed to the process being started.

Then there's the `call`. This invokes a parser trick. Suppose `%%e` is `2`. The command would be executed as `call start "Instance 2" u:\dummy.bat %%commandvar%%e%%` where `%%commandvar%%e%%` would be interpreted left-to-right as `%commandvar2%` as `%` is the "escape character" for `%`. Escaping a character is where we want to use a character without its special meaning. `%%e` is replaced by `2` first because it's an active `metavariable` (loop-control character or parameter-number). `CALL`in the resultant command `start "Instance 2" u:\dummy.bat %commandvar2%` then substitutes the current value of `commandvar2` for the process.

=== Summary thought ===

With this new approach to have multiple `commandvaar` entries, there appears to be no reason for the nomination of a number of entries and then checking that number, so that entire section could be regarded as redundant.

If you remove that section, then there's no reason for the restriction to 9 items. You could set the limit to any number you like by replacing the `9` with 22, 35, 957 - whatever takes your fancy. The process will now start whenever you reply <kbd>Enter</kbd> to a prompt `Insert ID for instance ??:`

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer. I learned some from your answer.
I have tried your commands and everything works just fine. I just have two issues.
1. How can I make it to actually show the time countdown with this:
"for /L %%y in (1,1,20) do (
 timeout /t 1 > nul"
I know removing > nul displays the time but because it checks every 1 second, It would not work as a solution.
2. for the
"set "commandvar1="
set "commandvar2="
set /P CommandVar1=Insert ID: 
if not defined commandvar1 goto begin"
part, How can I add more than one commandvar? (e.g. commandvar5)
Thanks again!

Comment: Include after the `for /L` a line `echo %%y`. This would show 1,2 etc. Strictly, you may want to insert that line after the `timeout` line. Try both and take your choice. If you want to count down, change the `(1,1,10)` to `(10,-1,1)`. There *is* a method to have the count appear on a single line (this way, you would have each count on a new line) but it's probably a little complicated. The reason I chose this method is to allow the timeout to be changed easily and to exit the loop as soon as the processes have terminated instead of waiting for the full 10 seconds to elapse.

Comment: You *could* also change the `for /L` line to `for %%y in (Ten Nine Eight ...)` which would do the obvious. Of course, this is optional. You could remove the `for` and set the timeout to 10. All under your control...

Comment: Great. I found this I think it works pretty well:

"setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F %%# in ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" NUL') do set "CR=%%#"
for /L %%n in (20 -1 0) do (
    <nul set /p ".=Countdown [%%n] !CR!"
    ping localhost -n 2 > nul
)
"

Answer (score -1):

Parham.8, the error level is set after each command has been executed, if the next command succeeds, the error level will take 0 independent of the previous one. Use && to execute a command only if the previous command's error level is 0. Ex.

```
start EXAMPLE.exe %CommandVar1% && start EXAMPLE.exe %CommandVar2% && tasklist /fi "imagename eq EXAMPLE.exe" |find ":" > nul
```